# RLException: neither a launch file package nor a launch file name

Tags: ros, robotics-library, rviz

To get straight to the point I want to know how to fix this error and understand it, what is an RLException? Why am I getting this? How can I avoid this later? Below I will post what I did step by step:

This is the directory where I have my files

```
~/Desktop/Research/research_ws
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
RLException: [ddrobot_rviz.launch] is neither a launch file in package [ros_robotics] nor is [ros_robotics] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

The following are the codes for `dd_robot.urdf` and `ddrobot_rviz.launch` respectively:

```
<robot name="dd_robot">
    
    <!-- Base Link -->
    <link name ="base_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz = "0 0 0" rpy = "0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <box size = ".5 .5 .25"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
    </link>
</robot>
```

```
    <!-- values passed by command line input -->
    <arg name = "model" />
    <arg name = "gui" default ="False" />
    
    <!-- Set these parameters on Parameter Server -->
    <param name = "robot_description"
        textfile = "$(find ros_robotics)/urdf/$(arg model)" />
    <param name = "use_gui" value = "$(arg gui)" />
    
    <!-- Start 3 nodes: joint_state_publisher, robot_state_publisher
    rviz -->
    <node name = "joint_state_publisher" pkg = "joint_state_publisher"
            type = "joint_state_publisher" />
    <node name = "robot_state_publisher" pkg = "robot_state_publisher"
            type = "state_publisher" />
    <node name = "rviz" pkg = "rviz" type = "rviz" 
        args = "-d $(find ros_robotics)/urdf.rviz"
        required = "true" />
</launch>
```

I do not yet completely understand what is written in the above codes, I'm following the **ROS robotics by example** book *Fairchild*.

Answer (score 3):

I just had to re-enter:

```
source devel/setup.bash
```

In every new terminal.

Comment: Yes.  Alternatively, you can add that line to your `.bashrc` file so you don't have to remember to source it in every new terminal.